# Google Cloud Storage "upload cannot be completed" w/ error: "storage.objects.create"

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Been using the Google Cloud Storage to upload archives of my files weekly, until suddenly this error now appears.

> Upload cannot be completed
>
> > You don't have permission to upload files to this bucket. Contact the bucket or project owner to be given the "storage.objects.create" permission.

I have tried to grant myself the storage.objects.create permission, even when on the very same page I can verify I have that very permission it still complains that I do not have it.

Comment: How are you uploading your archives?  Are you using gsutil or some other mechanism?

Comment: Make sure you don't have a typo in your bucket name. Might be trying to upload to someone else's bucket...

Comment: Could you please explain how are you trying to upload the files? In case you are using a programmatic way, maybe it can be  about an expired TOKEN.

Comment: I just drag and drop my file in as I have always done. Here is a screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/ArfIr5h

Comment: Could you please edit your question and provide the HAR file ( https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204410413-Generating-a-HAR-file-for-troubleshooting)  from when are you trying to do this operation? Please keep in mind that the HAR files could contains sensitive data, so try to sanitize it before sending it, using this tool  ( https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/har_analyzer/ ). Could you also check your Stackdriver logs for any "permission deneid" message and then try to upload with another method like using "gsutil"?My guess is that it is an U.I. issue.

Comment: @AndreiTigau I tried again now with a text file, but had no error. I will try again on the weekend when I have my next archive ready.

Comment: @AndreiTigau So I normally just drag and drop my archive, but on a whim tried to use the "upload files" button instead. That actually worked!

Comment: Sometimes Drag n Drop and the upload-button works, sometimes it doesn't. To this day I do not know why. I just discovered: In the Edge, GCS won't accept my file. In the chrome, GCS accepts the file. "Ein Schelm, wer böses dabei denkt ..." It seems that I used to login with this and that browser. ->For everyone else who, like I found here via google: Try another browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical U.I. internal issue on GCP. More people had this issue and it was solved. You can use the upload button as a workaround, but in order to solve it you have 2 options. In case you are entitled to have support you can [open a support ticket](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/procedures), stating your context. The other option, in case you are not entitled for support is creating a [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187225&template=0).

To investigate this issue further, the entitled teams will need you to record a HTTP Archive [HAR](http://%20https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.har) while
recreating the steps that led to the error, then attach the saved HAR file to
the issue description. HAR files contain header and request information for a browsing
session and are useful for troubleshooting a variety of problems. Detailed
instructions can be found [here](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/har_analyzer/).

A HAR file can contain sensitive information including, but not limited to,
passwords, cookies, private keys and credit card numbers. As such, it is better that you review the generated HAR file, and sanitize it of any such
information.

Additionally, it is advised that you sign out of any sessions that were active
during the time that the HAR file was generated in order to invalidate them.
Incognito mode is not enough to guarantee this, as the session may still be
active, even after closing the incognito window.